# Caching functions instead of require_once in php

Tags: function, caching, apc, require

I've been using APC caching functions and it's been phenomenal. I was thinking, why not just cache all of my functions, and load them whenever I need to (kind of like frameworks actually).

```
function Foo {echo 'bar';}
$foo = Foo;
apc_store('foo',$foo);
```

And then whenever Foo is needed, I'd just use apc_fetch. Is that more efficient/quick than require_once?
Is it a smart move to do? (especially when you have a lot of function files)